# Update SQLITE database iterating through a JSON object

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
import json
import codecs

conn = sqlite3.connect('geodata.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Locations')

for row in cur :
    print(row[0])
    data = row[1]
    try: 
        js = json.loads(data)
    except: 
        continue
    
        
    lati = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]

    cur.execute("UPDATE Locations SET lat = ? WHERE address =?",(str(lati),row[0]))
    print(lati,lng)
    conn.commit()
```

Hello all, I new to python and in this piece of code I'am trying to read the latitude and longitude of several locations and populating a SQLITE database with the corresponding lat and long for each location . The latitude and longitude are read from a JSON object. I am able to successfully read the lat and long but I am not able to populate the respective lat and long fields in the database. I not getting any error message. I am just not able to populate the lat and long fields

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: What does print(lati,lng) return? is address your primary key? I would have thought it would be id.

Comment: Hi Madison, it does return the lat and long for all location. I just need to write this data to the database in the corresponding and lat and long for each location.Yes, address is the primary key.

Comment: AGH University of Science and Technology 50.0676785 19.9070824